# Cannot Resolve symbol ActivityCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library

Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityCompat' 
I am trying to send SMS through my application.
I have added uses permission on AndroidManifest.xml as well

ActivityCompat is not resolving help me out.

complie Sdk version is 25

```
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(sendSMS2.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is not granted
            // Ask for permision
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] { Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
        }
```

here is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.somme.testproj2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

}
```

Comment: Post your Gradle file

Comment: post your app `build.gradle` dependencies

Comment: how can I post ?

Comment: like above copy and past

Comment: check the updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using this,

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0'
```

Answer (score 16):

In case anyone is here after shifting to androidx,
import

```
androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
```

instead of

```
android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
```

In case of confusions regarding which new androidx class replaces the old support library class, refer [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings) androidx migration class mapping and just search for the class you'd like to replace and replace it with the corresponding androidx class.

P.S. - I know this doesn't answer this question per se. Just leaving it here for anyone else who might land here because of the question title.

Comment: What do I replace `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` with ?

Comment: @SeanMC.. You can import this - androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.

Comment: In general, you can refer to the class mappings specified in the link in my updated answer when confused :)

Comment: Thanks. My particular issue, with Capacitor, was solved by deleting my node_modules folder and then doing npm install. Then all my class mappings were applied. Not sure, it might have been an issue with jetifier.

Answer (score 1):

You have not added support v4 appcompat library in your project,

ActivityCompat class belongs to v4 support library, check documentation from here

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat

add following library to your module build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:+'
```

Comment: could not find com.android.support:collections:28.0.0-alpha3. after added what above library in build.gradle

Comment: you need to have it same as your all other support libraries so instead of + add 25.0.0 to import for specific version

Comment: did you try to clean and build the project after adding dependencies

Comment: i also want the message that I would send through this , having 4 digit numbers. means the recipient receive the message from 4 digit number. how is that possible

Comment: you need to move this code in else part `SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);`

Comment: my application has permission by default to send the sms so I don't have IF ELSE in this code block